# Java code to find balance no of days in a financial year

Tags: java

How to find the balance number of days in the current financial year in java. For eg balance days upto march 31.

```
if(Integer.parseInt(currentmonth)<4){
    currentyears=Integer.parseInt(currentyear)-1;
    finMonth=Integer.parseInt(currentmonth)+9;
    remainMonth=12-finMonth;        
}else{  
    currentyears=Integer.parseInt(currentyear);
    finMonth=Integer.parseInt(currentmonth)-3;
    remainMonth=12-finMonth;
}
```

This is my code for finding the financial year. My Problem is to find the remaining days in the financial year.

Comment: What problem are you facing?? It just needs few comparison and subtraction..? Have you tried anything.. Post some code here..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjusting_entries ?

Comment: @ramkumar: please re-read your comment and ask yourself: have I supplied *any* information in that comment that was not already part of the question? If not, then what good does that comment do?

Comment: if(Integer.parseInt(currentmonth)<4)
  {
   currentyears=Integer.parseInt(currentyear)-1;
   finMonth=Integer.parseInt(currentmonth)+9;
   remainMonth=12-finMonth;
   
   
  }
  else
  { 
   currentyears=Integer.parseInt(currentyear);
   finMonth=Integer.parseInt(currentmonth)-3;
   remainMonth=12-finMonth;
  }

Comment: In that code how can i find balance no of days from today

Comment: @ram kumar, please **edit** your post with code that you think is the issue instead of putting it as a comment.

Comment: How to find the balance number of days in a year.

Comment: Have you looked at java.util.Date? It might replace most of your calculations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started :

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DaysLeft {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        int max_days = cal.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        int days_left = max_days - today;

        System.out.format("We have a maximum of %d days this year.\n", max_days);
        System.out.format("Today is day number %d.\n", today);
        System.out.format("That means we have %d days left this year.\n",days_left);
    }       
}
```

It calculates how many days are in a year, what day today is and how many days are left in the year. Of course, you will have to adapt it to suit your needs. Good luck!

Comment: How to get a double value without rounding off in java

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example? It sounds like a different question though?